# What is the raku equivalent of the JavaScript arrow function?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, raku

In JavaScript, I can go

```
const materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

console.log(materials.map(material => material.length));
// expected output: Array [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

I guess that raku has some chops in functional - and I wonder if someone can clarify the equivalent code (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions )

Comment: What feature of arrow functions are you looking to replicate? Lexical `this` binding? Short-hand syntax where the body of the function is an expression rather than a block? The ability to create a function using the `=>` symbols?

Comment: hi @quentin - the latter i.e. ability to create a function with ```=>```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The most direct equivalent would be

```
my @materials = <Hydrogen Helium Lithium Beryllium>;
say @materials.map(-> $material { $material.chars });
```

but an arrow sub is more explicit than you need in this case, because

```
say @materials.map: *.chars;
```

would also be sufficient (method call on a "whatever star" returns a code block that calls that method on its argument), and

```
say @materials».chars;
```

would also work (hyper-application applied to the dot operator).

Comment: thanks @hobbs - I'm sidling up to functional and had not (yet) figured that whatever ```*``` currying is the ultimate shorthand -cool!

Comment: And as another 'nother option: `@materials.map: { .chars }` (useful for single arguments where you might need to use the arg >2 times since you can do, e.g., `{ .substr(0,1) ~ '…' .substr(*-1) }`.